# Why is my internal microphone not working on Ubuntu and other Ubuntu based distros?

Tags: microphone

So I have a TUF Gaming FX505DD_FX505DD laptop with the AMD Ryzen 5 3550H. I've tested Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, UbuntuDDE, and ubuntu-based distros such as Mint, Zorin, Feren, and only on ubuntuDDE is my internal microphone working. I've searched for a while now and tried some of the supposed fixes and none of them work for me. I am talking about the salsa and pulse audio commands that I always see ppl talk about. Even installing other kernels don't fix it. Well, at least one time I tested a 4.15 something kernel and boot into it and it was working but my desktop resolution was out of wack and I didn't even see an option to select my native 1920*1080, and definitely wasn't recognizing my Dedicated GPU. I always only see ppl talking about intel cards and not AMD. Is there a fix that I don't know about for this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and those based on that version.

Comment: Btw I tested another ubuntu-based distro which is Pop OS but the 20.10 one and the microphone works. Maybe that issue is fixed in Ubuntu 20.10. Since I've now tested two different distros based on 20.10, it "might" be safe to say it's fixed in Ubuntu 20.10. And I noticed that the kernel is 5.8.0...